# Error when creating histogram of data that is of class times in R

Tags: r, error-handling, histogram

Suppose I have the following data (hours,minutes,seconds)

```
z <- as.times(c("00:07:26","00:10:26","01:07:00"))
```

And I would like to create a histogram where I label the x-axis

```
hist(z, xlab = "Time")
```

I then get the following error: Warning: argument ‘xlab’ is not made use of

I do not know why this appears and I am unable to resolve it

Comment: Where does the `as.times` function come from? That's not a base R function. Perhaps that package also overload the `hist` function

Comment: My guess: the `chron` package, which does provide an S3method [`hist.times`](https://github.com/cran/chron/blob/a90a1da59211354bc380f2e5b353922c203e190d/R/times.R#L312-L374), which unfortunately appears to not provide a method for naming (or overriding) axes.

Comment: The as.times indeed comes from the chron package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MrFlick commented, I couldn't find the source for the `as.times` function you are using. Using `hms()` from the `lubridate` package instead your plot function works as expected:

```r
z <- lubridate::hms(c("00:07:26","00:10:26","01:07:00"))
hist(z@minute, xlab = 'Time (Minutes)')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I am wondering though how I should interpret the values on the x axis

Comment: Hi @WHN, please see the histogram function in the edited answer I posted. Lubridate returns a [period class](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/period.html) object, and you can specify which unit to work with in the histogram.

Comment: This format may not be useful for what you're hoping to do. Converting the periods to another unit might make more sense, e.g. `hist(period_to_seconds(z), xlab = 'Time')`